# Async finish first then mainActivity starts

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I got a problem I need to solve to be able to parse my menu items in my navigation drawer.
Everything works fine: my asyncTask to get my xml feed of the internet and parse it into variables but, I want to use variable as menu items for my navigation drawer. My navigation drawer is called in my MainActivity its onCreate so that will be executed as first at the same time the asyncTask is running.

My question to this is: is there a way to finish the asyncTask first and then execute my Mainactivity its lifecycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create some kind of `SplashActivity` during which you will download the list from the web and on its `onPostExecute` you can launch your main activity, passing the data you got with the `Intent`.

Comment: Make sure to check for the Intent data first before using it, if your AsyncTask fails at retrieving result and you start the activity, the data might be null and will give you an exception.

Comment: @Nightware Yes I already tried something with an intent and yes just as you said the intent was giving a null.